# ruby sybase connection through dbi, issues with native sybase driver class name to be used in connection string

Tags: ruby, sybase, dbi

Anyone has successfully connected to `sybase db` using `dbi` in Ruby?

I can't seem to construct a connection string for this.

```
dbh = DBI.connect('dbi:<xyz>:<db-name>','<user-name>', '<pwd>' )
```

Below is the format of the error I get -

```
 C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:300:in `load_driver': Unable to load driver '<xyz>' (underlying error: uninitialized constant DBI::DBD::<db-name>) (DBI::InterfaceError)
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:242:in `load_driver'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:160:in `_get_full_driver'
from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:145:in `connect'
from C:/Simple/algo/db.rb:13
```

I use native `sybase drivers to` connect to `sybase db` when I connect through another rails app but can't seem to locate it's name. (Please let me know if there is a way to find db driver name in a working rails app using some `command`/ `global variable` or something).

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using SybSQL instead of DBI did the thing.

```
query=SybSQL.new({'S'=>@@server,'U'=>@@user,'P'=>@@passwd})
```

Comment: Could you post more examples of this?